# According to Reformed theology, how should Christians react when a non-believer dies?

Tags: reformed-theology, hell, non-christians

Several of the Scriptures seem to indicate that God's judgement is righteous, wonderful, and something to long for. Here are a few examples:

> "Yea, in the way of thy judgments, O YHVH, have we waited for thee; the desire of our soul is to thy name, and to the remembrance of thee.
>
> With my soul have I desired thee in the night; yea, with my spirit within me will I seek thee early: for when thy judgments are in the earth, the inhabitants of the world will learn righteousness." Isaiah 26:8-9

Also:

> "The fear of YHVH is clean, enduring for ever: the judgments of YHVH are true and righteous altogether." Psalm 19:9

And:

> "Zion heard, and was glad; and the daughters of Judah rejoiced because of thy judgments, O YHVH." Psalm 97:8

According to the Reformed church, how should Christians (of any sort) react when an unbeliever (specifically those that have outright denied Christianity: ex. Atheist, Muslims, Hindu, non-Trinitarians) dies and God subjects their flesh to be burned forever and ever in agonizing pain?

This is similar to *[Do Calvinists rejoice in the destruction of sinners?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/do-calvinists-rejoice-in-the-destruction-of-sinners)*, except that question is based on a faulty interpretation of Jonathan Edwards *Sinners in the Hands of an Angry God*. My question involves Scripture that explicitly says we should desire, be glad, and rejoice because of God's judgment; and how we can reconcile this with non-believers having their flesh burned forever and ever.

Comment: Can one not both rejoice in the Lord's perfect judgement and mourn the person's decisions which led to that judgement? Also, are you making an assumption of Particular Judgement here? Reformed theology is not unified on that. For example, I believe that eternal judgement would come all at once for all near the end, not as they die. So that may effect things. I mourn now but will rejoice then?

Comment: @Joshua Thank you for the comment. It doesn't matter which eschatology one believes in. Are you saying that we should mourn their bad decision, but rejoice in God's perfect judgment to have their flesh burned with fire forever and ever? I'm a bit confused about the second part also. Are you saying that you mourn now, while their bodies are in the grave, but you will rejoice when they are thrown into the eternal hellfire? Maybe I'm mistaken, but from what I see in the Scriptures, we should be rejoicing now.

Comment: like it or not you are presupposing a certain eschatology when you say things like that. Annihilationists might have some disagreements with you. Anyway. What makes you think these OT passages are speaking of final judgement anyway? Why can't they just be about righteous justice and law? The Psalms speak about laws and precepts in the same way.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not aware of any official sects within the Reformed church that teach annihilationism. Is that what you believe in? These passages speak of God's righteous judgements in general. I'm having trouble seeing a difference between His "righteous justice" and His ultimate judgment concerning hell.  Are you saying that God's righteous justice and law is good, but His final judgement to send people to eternal hell fire is excluded from righteousness, goodness, and something to desire and rejoice over?

Comment: Take a look at Mr. Bultitude's answer to the suggested duplicate question – the quotes given there should help you understand the way in which Calvinists react.

Comment: Does any Christian group teach that humans can know the heart of another human and thus be able to declare what judgement they will receive from God? No anyone who declares otherwise is presumptuous and ought to be looking into their own heart rather than trying to peer into another persons. Judge ye not !

Comment: @Nathaniel, I'm considering whether this answers my question. Some rejoice because God did not elect the sinners so they deserve to burn forever, some rejoice because everyone else is being burned but "we understand that we could have been what they are.", and the last quote under Yes doesn't seem to say anything about how Christians should react. The other group is sad because God carried out His righteous and good judgement to burn non-believers flesh forever. I feel like the first two quotes under Yes answer my question, but I'm not sure. I have to go to bed, so is it okay if I sleep on it?

Comment: Sure! Sleep well.

Comment: Okay @Nathaniel. I believe the first two quotes under Yes in *Do Calvinists rejoice in the destruction of sinners?* answers my question. Thank you for digging that up for me.

Comment: @anonymouswho there is at least one reformed theology Protestant denomination that does teach annihilationism. The one I am a member of. We as a community need to stop thinking that our lack of knowledge of something means it does not exist. acgc.us/

Comment: @Joshua "while the wicked will be punished with everlasting destruction; suffering complete extinction of being." This is from the site you provided. Interesting. From what I understand, this is considered heresy, correct? Also, I cannot seem to find anything that says Advent Christian General Conference is Reformed. The About page says it was born out of the Adventist Movement. I did find out there is a Seventh Day Adventist Reformed Movement, but it seems to be very controversial. If you can provide an answer and explain why ACAG is Reformed, I'll definitely consider accepting it. Thank you

Comment: @anonymouswho Because I because I attended their undergraduate school and know their theology is Reformed? Depends on whose orthodoxy you are accepting, but there is nothing in the Three Creeds it violates. We're off topic. Point was I was trying too clarify how big a part the exact definition of the final judgment was to your question. It seems to be intentionally emotionally slanting your question.

Comment: @Joshua The final sentence of the Athanasian Creed (written in the fifth or sixth century) states "And they that have done good shall go into life everlasting; and they that have done evil, into everlasting fire." This is the only definition of final judgment that I have to go on when it concerns the Reformed church (or any that accept this creed). I'm sorry, but if you or anyone else can provide information that confirms ACAG is a Reformed church rather than strictly Adventist, then I'll accept it. As far as the order of events leading to flesh burning forever, it doesn't matter to me.

Comment: @anonymouswho I'm not sure what me convincing you the ACGC is Reformed has to do with my clarification question. What difference does it make to your question if they are burned in conscious eternity or simply consumed for eternity in a fire? If it does matter then it seems your question has more to do with questioning the justice of eternal conscious torment than it does with how we react to people dying at this time. I'm not going down that rabbit trail. Read the wiki for annihilationism if you are really curious.